# Изменение объекта в другом процессе

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо в объекте хранить информацию о ходе выполнения кода. Для этого я решил реализовать свой класс. Но как заставить это работать?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Report:
    __report = ''

    def __init__(self):
        self.__report = ''

    def write(self, rep):
        self.__report += '\n' + rep

    def get_all(self):
        return self.__report

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.__report + '\n' + str(other)
        return self

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.__report += '\n' + str(other)
        return self


def a(r):
    r += '123'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Report()
    t += '321'
    print(t.get_all())
    p = Process(target=a, args=(t,))
    p.start()
    print(t.get_all())
```

Вывод:

```
321

321
```

Желаемый вывод:
    321

```
321
123
```

Что я делаю не так? Без процесса код работает

Comment: [У двух процессов совершенно раздельные переменные, никак не связанные между собой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303)

Comment: попробуйте начать с [примеров кода в документации multiprocessing модуля](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Comment: Уже решил костылём через очереди. Всем спасибо